# Limit number of rows - TSQL - Merge - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi all i have the following merge sql script which works fine for a relatively small number of rows (up to about 20,000 i've found). However sometimes the data i have in Table B can be up to 100,000 rows and trying to merge this with Table A (which is currently at 60 million rows). This takes quite a while to process, which is understandable as it has to merge 100,000 with 60 million existing records!

I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this. Or is it possible to have some sort of count, so merge 20,000 rows from Table B to Table A. Then delete those merged rows from table B. Then do the next 20,000 rows and so on, until Table B has no rows left?

Script:

```
MERGE
    Table A AS [target]
USING
    Table B AS [source]
ON
    ([target].recordID = [source].recordID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT([recordID],[Field 1]),[Field 2],[Field 3],[Field 4],[Field 5])
        VALUES([source].[recordID],[source].[Field 1],[source].[Field 2],[source].[Field 3],[source].[Field 4],[source].[Field 5]
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MERGE` is overkill for this since all you want is to `INSERT` missing values.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A
([recordID],[Field 1]),[Field 2],[Field 3],[Field 4],[Field 5])
SELECT  B.[recordID],
        B.[Field 1],B.[Field 2],B.[Field 3],B.[Field 4],B.[Field 5]
FROM Table_B as B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A A
                  WHERE A.RecordID = B.RecordID)
```

In my experience `MERGE` can perform worse for simple operations like this.  I try to reserve it for when you need varying operations depending on conditions, like an UPSERT.

Comment: I did have something like this before, however found Merge to be slightly better in terms of performance. However if i was to use something like you have said, is it possible to again batch the rows to insert into Table A from Table B?

Comment: Sure, just add `TOP 20000` after the `SELECT`.  It will only select the top 20k rows that don't already exist.

Comment: @Vince - Also, please bear in mind `EXISTS` is a lot faster than your previous method from the other question of `LEFT JOIN...IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do `(SELECT TOP 20000 * FROM B ORDER BY [some_column]) as [source]` in `USING` and then delete these records after `MERGE`. So you pseudo-code will look like :

```
1. Merge top 20000
2. Delete 20000 records from source table
3. Check @@ROWCOUNT. If it's 0, exit; otherwise goto step 1
```

I'm not sure if it runs any faster than merging all the records at the same time. 
Also, are you sure you need `MERGE`? From what I see in your code `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` should also work for you.

Comment: @Siva: Ok, I got it. I still doubt that it's a proper usage of `merge` which is capable of doing more tasks, but it may end up with the same performance as `insert` in this case. I don't think `merge` that just inserts records can be faster than "pure" `insert` unless there is a serious bug in `insert` implementation...